Distance between peaks in 1H-NMR multiplets
In discussing coupled spins, OpenStax Organic Chemistry shows the following NMR spectrum:
The figure caption claims that "the distance between peaks is the same in both multiplets". They don't give any quantitive data (and we don't know at which field strength the spectrum was taken). Visually, it seems like the peak separation is larger for the methyl group doublet. Is there any way to figure out the actual peak separation from this figure?

Karsten, I think the x-scale (inset) for both is not the same. They should have shown the axes. Later they show that the distance is 7 Hz.

Check Reaxys and SciFinder for their NMR. This molecule should be well studied.

The figure is not helpful if you want to compare the splittings. If the inset expansions are not shown at the same scale the splittings will not be equal. Moreover, the absence of a scale in the insets does not allow a confident quantitative analysis. I checked with a ruler and it would appear they are not quite the same (difference of about 10-20%). In addition, the resolution in the original spectrum is too poor to evaluate the size of the separation).
J-couplings (typically reported in frequency units of Hz) do not depend on the strength of the applied field, so the field strength does not influence the magnitude of peak separation within simple splittings (standard binomial-type or $\ce{A_nX_m}$) when described in Hz units. However, at higher field strengths the separation between peaks within a simple multiplet decreases when expressed in ppm. Multiplets have a tendency to become simpler at higher fields because the spectral dispersion increases. Dispersion refers to the separation between multiplets in frequency units. The dispersion increases linearly with the magnitude of the applied field, even though the separation between multiplets in ppm (shift units) remains constant.

Yes, I've seen other spectra where the insets have a scale, too (e.g Fig 6.7e here). In that case, you can get away with showing insets at different x-scales. The peak height of the insets often is adjusted for better viewing, which is fine.
